# Info on SPARQL Queries

Tags: sparql

I need to work on SPARQL queries. Does any one has good links to learn SPARQL queries? I am looking good article on syntax of the SPARQL queries and examples so that I could learn it quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please pardon the shameless plug, but O'Reilly recently released my book "Learning SPARQL," which so far is the only book on the query language. As title implies, it's more about getting up to speed with SPARQL than about providing a complete reference work. The book covers both SPARQL 1.0 and 1.1. See learningsparql.com for more; all sample queries and data are available on the website.

Answer (score 4):

Lee Feigenbaum's [SPARQL by Example](http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/#%281%29) is always a good place to start.

If you have specific questions you'll find a helpful bunch of people containing many SPARQL experts at answers.semanticweb.com

Answer (score 2):

here's all the resources i've been collecting to start from and i've found them very useful

**pat 1 introduction :**

1. Introducing RDFS & OWL
   http://www.linkeddatatools.com/introducing-rdfs-owl
2. Query semantic Data
   http://www.linkeddatatools.com/querying-semantic-data

**part 2 : detailed**

1. introduction to RDF : 
   http://www.slideshare.net/olafhartig/an-introduction-to-rdf-and-the-web-of-data
2. SPARQL By Example
   http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/#%281%29
3. introduction to SparQl : 
   http://www.slideshare.net/olafhartig/an-introduction-to-sparql
4. SparQl Slides : (query from linked data )
   http://www.slideshare.net/olafhartig/querying-linked-data-with-sparql

**part 3: linked data endpoints**

1. SPARQL Generic end point http://sparql.org/sparql.html
2. MUSIC Brainz http://dbtune.org/musicbrainz/snorql/
3. DBpedia http://dbpedia.org/sparql

Answer (score 0):

If you like jumping to examples first, you can refer the official W3C specifications document http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-sparql11-query-20130321/

Contains a good amount of examples , and are edited by top people . Should take about less than 10 minutes to finish too